# preg_replace regular expression to replace link within a particular tags

Tags: replace, preg-replace, href

I need one help, i want to replace the href link to my link within a particular div class only.

```
<div id="slider1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="imagens">
      <a href="http://oldsite.com/the-fate-of-the-furious"><img src="https://image.oldste.org" alt="The Fate of the Furious" width="100%" height="100%" /></a>
      <span class="imdb">
        <b class="icon-star"></b> N/A
      </span>
    </div>
    <span class="ttps">The Fate of the Furious</span>
    <span class="ytps">2017</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here i want to change http://oldsite.com/ to http://newsite.com/?id=

i want these href links like

```
<a href="http://newsite.com/?id=the-fate-of-the-furious">
```

Please help me with preg_replace regular expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
     $content = get_the_content();
     $pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";
     $newurl = get_permalink();
     $content = preg_replace($pattern,$newurl,$content);

     echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehinds are too expensive, use `\K` to start the fullstring match and avoid a capture group.

`<a href="\K[^"]+\/`  This pattern will be very efficient.  I should state that this pattern will match ALL `<a href` urls.  It also matches greedily until it finds the last `/` in the url -- I assume this is okay by your input sample.

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9O3enL/2)

Code ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ceeb28752786245d1b1c282197ef257e9f733ed2)):

```
$in='<div id="slider1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item">
<div class="imagens">
<a href="http://oldsite.com/the-fate-of-the-furious"><img src="https://image.oldste.org" alt="The Fate of the Furious" width="100%" height="100%" /></a>
<span class="imdb"><b class="icon-star"></b> N/A</span>
</div>
<span class="ttps">The Fate of the Furious</span>
<span class="ytps">2017</span>
</div>';

echo preg_replace('/<a href="\K[^"]+\//','http://newsite.com/?id=',$in);
```

Output:

```
<div id="slider1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item">
<div class="imagens">
<a href="http://newsite.com/?id=the-fate-of-the-furious"><img src="https://image.oldste.org" alt="The Fate of the Furious" width="100%" height="100%" /></a>
<span class="imdb"><b class="icon-star"></b> N/A</span>
</div>
<span class="ttps">The Fate of the Furious</span>
<span class="ytps">2017</span>
</div>
```